# warning:mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am getting the above warning when I try to run this code:

```
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost", "***", "***","***") or die(mysql_error());


              function checklogin($username, $password){
                global $mysqli;


                $result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
                $result->bind_param("s", $username);
                $result->execute();

            if($result != false){

                $dbArray=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Answer (score 44):

You are mixing mysql and mysqli calls in your code. Use `mysqli_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`.

Answer (score 8):

You are mixing `mysqli`  and traditional `mysql` commands.

Use [`$result->fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Comment: The first line should also use $mysqli->connect_error, not mysql_error().

Comment: But now I get : Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array() in /var/www/JMToday/loginchk.php on line 52

Comment: @Sam you need to use `query()` instead of `execute()`, that returns a result object that contains the `fetch_array` method. See here for a full example: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 1):

You're using two different sets of functions... mysqli and mysql.
I think you want to use the fetch_assoc() method.

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php